# Cannot call value of non-function type '((UInt) -> Data?)!' with Alamofire 4

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I'm trying convert code for Swift 3 and Alamofire 4, and I'm currently struggling with the following error:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type '((UInt) -> Data?)!'
```

at this line:

```
multipartFormData.append(data: value!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, name: key)
```

Please give your advice for this case. My current code is below.

```
Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "image", fileName: nowString + "To" + receiverString! + ".jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(data: value!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, name: key)
        }
    },to:"uploadimgURL"
      encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _)                    
            upload.responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
                debugPrint(response)
            })

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: change parameters to [String: String] type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do see one issue with the line in question. Try not using the raw value of the enum like so:

```
let stringValue = value as! String
multipartFormData.append(data: stringValue.data(using: .utf8)!, name: key)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice ! I did above, received "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Any'"...

Comment: That is likely from the value variable. Try removing the ! after value.

Comment: `multipartFormData.append(data: value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8), name: key)` ->Value of type 'Any' has no member 'data'

Comment: pre def -> `let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myDrawingImageView.image!, 1) let parameters = ["lastName" : receiverLabelText.text, "userId" : randomURL + nowString ] as [String : Any]`

Comment: Type parameters as [String : String]. Or force cast value: let stringValue = value as! String. Also, you still need the ! after the data method. You should give the Swift book another read to brush up on your fundamentals.

Comment: thank you for your advice ! this issue resolved from change Any to String.